# Parsing an xml with child nodes and converting to datatable in c#?

Tags: c#, xml, datatable

I have an xml file and I want to read it and convert it to a datatable in the following format. I have tried something but it doesnt seem to work. Any suggestions or help is highly appreciated ?

```
 <Country>KENYA</Country>
 <isAG1>
    <Age>47</Age>
    <Status>PASSED</Status>
  </isAG1>
  <Customer>New</Customer>
  <MnoResponse>
    <Date>2016-11-07</Date>
  <MnoResponse>
```

This is how I want my Datatable to look like-

```
Country |  isAG1_Age | isAG1_Status | Customer | MnoResponse_Date
 KENYA       47          PASSED        New           2016-11-07
```

This is what I tried so far - But it doesnt seem to read the child nodes 
and I also want to extend the head of the parent node with the child node as shown above.

```
DataSet d = new DataSet();
d.ReadXml("CustomerDetails.xml");
```

Comment: Xml Seialization and deserializarion should help you here.

Comment: Can you update xml to contains multiple rows.  You cannot use serialization like Chetan suggested since you want only 5 columns without writing code that moves the data from class(es) to the datatable.  It is much simplier to parse the xml and put data directly into datatable.  It is very simple, but need a larger xml sample.  Currently the xml is not well formed since there are multiple root tags.

Comment: You can parse input xml using XLinq and then generate datarows, datacolumn, datatable and dataset by parsed XElements like @jdweng suggested you